# Nodejs backend how get rid of html tags

Tags: node.js, axios

I have API that GET json data with axios from another site. Site require login but i get this data with token. It looks like this:

```
  "orders": [
    {
      "type": "some data",
      "id": some data,
      "number": "some data",
      "startAddress": "<b>some data<br>some data",
      "endAddress": "<b>some data</b><br>some data",
      "voivodeshipOfUnloadingId": some data,
      "distance": some data,
      "rate": some data,
      "supplement": some data,
      "lumpSum": some data,
      "sum": some data,
      "loadingDate": "some data",
      "status": 0,
      "comments": "<p>some data</p>",
      "isBlocked": false,
      "isCompleted": false,
      "index": 1
    } ]
```

How get rid of html tags ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple example: loop 'orders' array, then loop inner object properties and use string.replace with a regular expression to strip HTML tags.

Pay attention, this method mutates the original object, should you care.

```
 const obj = {
        'orders': [{
            'type': 'some data',
            'id': 'some data',
            'number': 'some data',
            'startAddress': '<b>some data<br>some data',
            'endAddress': '<b>some data</b><br>some data',
            'loadingDate': 'some data',
            'status': 0,
            'comments': '<p>some data</p>',
            'isBlocked': false,
            'isCompleted': false,
            'index': 1
        }]
    };

    for (order of obj.orders) {
        for (const field in order) {
            if (typeof order[field] === 'string') {
                order[field] = order[field].replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, '');
            }
        }
    }

    console.log(obj);
```

Output:

```
 {
  orders: [
    {
      type: 'some data',
      id: 'some data',
      number: 'some data',
      startAddress: 'some datasome data',
      endAddress: 'some datasome data',
      loadingDate: 'some data',
      status: 0,
      comments: 'some data',
      isBlocked: false,
      isCompleted: false,
      index: 1
    }
  ]
}
```